# Excel lookup table based on time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time, lookup

I need to set up a way that I can tell which shift certain things happen in.  I have a table that has all the times, but I would like to attach each time to a shift (i.e. if this happens between 14:00 & 22:00 it would be 2nd shift).  What is the best way to do this?  Lookup table?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question lacks details we need to help you. Please [edit] your question to include as much detail as you can; like what version of Excel, how your data is laid out, what you have attempted so far and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build a lookup table (note that it has to be sorted).

[image]

Then use VLOOKUP to return the 'approximate match'

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,D:E,2,TRUE)
```

The last argument for VLOOKUP is the 'range_lookup'

[image]

Which should do what you require :

[image]